# Why is an encoder + decoder model with L by L layers the same speed as as decoder only model with 2 L layers?

Tags: natural-language-processing, transformer

I was watching this lecture: https://youtu.be/27rNqGrTdSI?t=2295

In it the presenter stated that:

"An encoder + decoder model with L by L layers is actually the same speed as as decoder only model with 2 L layers because in the end the input and targets still have to be processed and decoder only concatenates inputs and targets to do most tasks. Technically, Encoder Decoder models are a form of sparsity, they are also sequentially sparse, they have dedicated parameters to inputs and targets, they different parameters for inputs and targets, parameter to flop ratio behaves differently from decoder only models"

Why is "An encoder + decoder model with L by L layers the same speed as as decoder only model with 2 L layers" true?